# Mac App: Auto-Resizing of subview doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, resize, interface-builder, nsview, autoresizingmask

I'm trying to code the tutorial on https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ (What’s New in Map Kit).

What I'd like to have is a Window with a map inside of it. If I resize the window, the map gets resized as well (just like in the tutorial).[image]

My problem is, that my MapView doesn't get enlarged as I zoom the Window. It just stays the size I initially set it to. In the tutorial the developer has constraints on his view. Maybe that's the reason, but on the View which holds the Map View the resize setting is set so, that descendants should be resized as well.

What setting am I missing? Unfortunately I don't have any code to show because the problem is related to Xcode / UI design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. After declaring the layout I had to add constraints to the view. After reading **Understanding Layout Constraints** in the documentation I was able to add the constraints to my user interface:

I had to click on this icon on the bottom right:
[image]
After that I could add the constraints to the view which holds my map view like this:

[image]